# Regular expression to allow single space in input field

Tags: regex

Regular expression to allow single space in an input field.if I have a field name "Name" so following string should be accepted and only characters are allowed.

```
 ABC ABC  //allowe
 abc abc //allowe
 abc ABC //allowe
 ABC abc //allowe
 abc abc abc // not allowe
 ABC ABC ABC // not allowe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for only characters:

```
[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+
```

There is an space between both `[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: Depending on where this is applied, it may well require anchors to actually prevent strings with multiple non-adjacent spaces from passing.